# Accessing RMI Server

Tags: java, rmi

I would like to access an existing RMI server. I do not have access to its source code, so I would like to set up a client that calls an existing service in the RMI Server.

What is the best way to create a client to invoke a particular method and can RMI be converted to a webservice?

Below is the class I have created:

```
package server;

import com.SerialService;
import java.rmi.Naming;

public class NewClass {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        //SerialService obj = null;
        try {

            SerialService obj = (SerialService) Naming.lookup("//localhost:8083/");
            System.out.println(obj.getSerial());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to get the RMI services client stub so you can call/compile against.  You would still need to know the port that the service is listening on.

```
import java.rmi.Naming;

public class RmiClient { 
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    RmiServerIntf obj = (RmiServerIntf)Naming.lookup("//localhost/RmiServer");
    System.out.println(obj.getMessage()); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello T, thanks for your response. What I did for now was access the compiled .jar file, and found the needed Interface. I am importing it but donno what to do onwards. In relevance to your suggestion, how can I get the RMI services client stub?

Comment: Hi again, I have used your example, provided the correct interface, but I got an exception:
java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub cannot be cast to Service. Does that mean that the lookup method has failed, in that case how can I find the RMI server url? by default I read that it operates by default on port 1099 (localhost), is that it?

Comment: update your question, show your code.  What is the name of the interface on the server you are trying to access?

Comment: @user3147473 You don't need to know the port the service is listening on. You do need to know the port the Registry is listening on; the name to which the service is bound in the Registry; and you need to have the remote interface(s) it implements, and maybe the stub class, available in your client's CLASSPATH. You cannot possibly get that `ClassCastException` from the code in this answer unless there is something very strange happening at the server.

Comment: Okay, is there a way to know the port the registery is listening on? Like a command? Is there a call which lists all registery services?

Comment: @user3147473 Unless you start the Registry in some default way y don't need to know, and if you start it in some non-default way you already know.